# lpr duplex ignoring blank page

Tags: printing, lpr

I'm trying to print double sided with the `lpr` command with `Duplex=DuplexNoTumble`. It's printing double sided, but skips/ignores blank pages. How can I fix this?

```
lpr -P ricoh -#1 -o fitplot -o Duplex=DuplexNoTumble -o page-ranges=1-16 MyDocument.pdf
```

Comment: What printer model is this? What printing system are you using (CUPS, LPRng, old BSD lpr — if you don't know tell us what distribution you're using)?

Comment: Hello Gilles, Printing system is using CUPS.